# Build Warnings after Upgrade Heroku 18 to 22

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems, heroku-cli

How do I manage the scout-APM warnings, getting during deployment on the Heroku staging server after upgrading Heroku versions(18-22) with config "ruby(3.1.2) and rails(6.0.3.3)"?

```
remote: I, [2022-09-07T13:32:05.994002 #19]  INFO -- : Raven 3.1.2 ready to catch errors
remote: [Scout] [09/07/22 13:32:06 +0000 release.7924 (19)] WARN : Exception loading instruments:
remote: [Scout] [09/07/22 13:32:06 +0000 release.7924 (19)] WARN : undefined method `call' for class `Redis::Client'
remote: 
remote:               alias_method :call_without_scout_instruments, :call
remote:               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
remote: Did you mean?  caller
remote: [Scout] [09/07/22 13:32:06 +0000 release.7924 (19)] WARN : [
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/scout_apm-5.3.1/lib/scout_apm/instruments/redis.rb:40:in `alias_method'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/scout_apm-5.3.1/lib/scout_apm/instruments/redis.rb:40:in `block in install'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/scout_apm-5.3.1/lib/scout_apm/instruments/redis.rb:29:in `class_eval'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/scout_apm-5.3.1/lib/scout_apm/instruments/redis.rb:29:in `install'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/scout_apm-5.3.1/lib/scout_apm/instrument_manager.rb:82:in `install_instrument'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/scout_apm-5.3.1/lib/scout_apm/instrument_manager.rb:37:in `install!'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/scout_apm-5.3.1/lib/scout_apm/agent.rb:41:in `install'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/scout_apm-5.3.1/lib/scout_apm.rb:223:in `block in <class:Railtie>'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'", 
  "/app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'", 
  "/app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'", 
  "/app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'", 
  "/app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'", 
  "/app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'", 
  "/app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'", 
  "/app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'", 
  "/app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'", 
  "/app/vendor/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'", 
  "/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/application.rb:339:in `require_environment!'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/application.rb:523:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `synchronize'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `invoke_prerequisites'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:218:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `synchronize'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `invoke_prerequisites'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:218:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `synchronize'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'", 
  "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'", 
  "/app/bin/rails:4:in `<main>'"]
```

Comment: What version of the `redis` gem do you have installed?

Comment: redis-rails 5.0.2 and redis 5.0.3

Comment: Solution:
   It's the ruby gem's version compatibility issue. I had used Redis '5.0.3' with split/dashboard before which caused this issue, now I have downgraded Redis gem to '4.0.6'  and it's working fine for me.